# Postgres query to return rows where json in the json column contains array elements more than one

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql

We are using Postgres DB , in that we have one table contains column of type JSON , format is like below

```
{
  "name" : "XXX",
  "id"  : "123",
  "course" :[
     {
       "name" : "java",
       "tutor":"YYYY"
     },
     {
       "name" : "python",
       "tutor":"ZZZZ"
     }

   ]  

}


{
  "name" : "XXX",
  "id"  : "123",
  "course" :[
     {
       "name" : "java",
       "tutor":"YYYY"
     },
     {
       "name" : "python",
       "tutor":"ZZZZ"
     }

   ]  

}
```

like this for example we have two rows , and in the json column we have each like above

i want to Postgre query , which will check the number of elements in the course array and if it is more than one , then only return that row

am not getting how to count the array elements from inside the json key

can any please suggest

Answer (score 0):

[why not just](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) `json_array_length`?.. eg:

```
f=# with c(j) as (values('{
  "name" : "XXX",
  "id"  : "123",
  "course" :[
     {
       "name" : "java",
       "tutor":"YYYY"
     },
     {
       "name" : "python",
       "tutor":"ZZZZ"
     }

   ]

}'::json))
select json_array_length(j->'course') from c;
 json_array_length
-------------------
                 2
(1 row)
```

so smth like

```
select * from table_name where json_array_length(j->'course') > 1
```